# Laravel 5.4 Unable to add custom css to layout/appl.blade

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-authorization

I am trying to customize the look of the login page for my laravel application.
Here is the file content structure that I have:

[image]

In the layouts/app.blade.php file I am trying to add a "app.min.1.css" css file:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="{{ asset('templates/admin/Template/css/app.min.1.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
                'csrfToken' = > csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>
</head>
```

so it's the app.min.css, but when I go and run my application I get a parsing error as follows:

[image]

The file is there and I did verify it, by creating an stan alone view to see if all the css file and js file were loaded correctly:

[image]

All I am trying to do is to use the existing Auth pages provided by laravel, but give them my own look and feel. Is it possible to add you own css and js files ?

Here is the code for the app.blade:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link href="{{ asset('templates/admin/Template/css/app.min.1.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script>
            window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
                    'csrfToken' = > csrf_token(),
            ]) !!};
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">

                        <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                        <!-- Branding Image -->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                            {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                        <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            &nbsp;
                        </ul>

                        <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <!-- Authentication Links -->
                            @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                            @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                           onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            @endif
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            @yield('content')
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
    </html>



here is the code for the auth/login/blade:

    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <div class="login" data-lbg="teal">
    <!-- Login -->
    <div class="l-block toggled" id="l-login">
        <div class="lb-header palette-Teal bg">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-circle"></i>
            Salve! Per favore effettui il login
        </div>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{                                                                          route('login') }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="lb-body">
                <div class="form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control fg-input">
                        <label class="fg-label">Indirizzo Email</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group fg-float ">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <input type="password" class="input-sm form-control fg-input">
                        <label class="fg-label">Password</label>


                    </div>
                </div>



                <button class="btn palette-Teal bg">Entra</button>

                <div class="m-t-20">
                    <a data-block="#l-register" data-bg="blue" class="palette-Teal text d-block m-b-5" href="">Crea un Account</a>
                    <a data-block="#l-forget-password" data-bg="purple" href=""                                  class="palette-Teal text">Password Dimenticata?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here.

Remove the space between `=` and `>` for `'csrfToken' = > csrf_token(),`

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) !!};
</script>
```

Comment: argh you are right! why does this always happen, it's so frustrating...anyway, thank you.

Comment: The joy of programming :)

Comment: You should accept this answer as correct if you believe this to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra space here:

```
                'csrfToken' = > csrf_token(),
```

Fix so that it is:

```
                'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
```